# Quartz job store is related to active data?

Tags: c#, .net, quartz.net

As I understood from [Quartz official documentation](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/lesson_9.html), AdoStore have to be used for active data storing like JobDataMap and other data. Correct me if I am wrong.

Beside of this clarification I would like to know is there any way to load job and trigger definition from database. Kind of plugin or something like the `Quartz.Plugin.Xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin` is for reading from xml file.

If there is not, is it the best solution to implement a custom plugin that will read from database or to use some other approach?

[EDIT] Rastko 8/13/2012 11:16:28 AM

From bellow answers I think that I have not describe you the problem good.
I would like to load job and trigger configuration from database. Like it is defined in code or in xml like this :

```
    <job>
  <name>WriterJob</name>
  <group>CommonGroup</group>
  <description>Test WriteJob</description>
  <job-type>Console.WriteJob, Console</job-type>
</job>
<trigger>
  <simple>
    <name>WriterJobTrigger</name>
    <group>CommonTriggerGroup</group>
    <description>Simple trigger to simply fire sample job</description>
    <job-name>WriterJob</job-name>
    <job-group>CommonGroup</job-group>
    <misfire-instruction>SmartPolicy</misfire-instruction>
    <repeat-count>-1</repeat-count>
    <repeat-interval>10000</repeat-interval>
  </simple>
</trigger>
```

I want to have this on the same way in DataBase. From generated tables for ADOJobStore I see that these tables are more related for tracking of the currently active jobs - tracking of its state, trigger firing, etc.

I hope that I more clear now. Be free to ask me if you need any additional clarification.

Comment: No, the database isn't **just** for active jobs. For example, the scheduler.AddJob(jobDetail, replace) method will add the details of a job to the database (QUARTZ_JOB_DETAILS table) even though it has no schedule attached and hence isn't active.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> I would like to know is there any way to load job and trigger definition from database.

If you are looking to retrieve a list of jobs from the database, you can do something like :

```
  Quartz.IScheduler scheduler ; 


   ....

  var details = (from groupName in scheduler.GetJobGroupNames()
                 from jobKey in scheduler.GetJobKeys(
                      Quartz.Impl.Matchers.GroupMatcher<Quartz.JobKey>
                      .GroupEquals(groupName))
                select new 
                { 
                    GroupName = groupName, 
                    JobName = jobKey.Name  , 
                    triggers = scheduler.GetTriggersOfJob(jobKey) 
                }
               );
```

This syntax is for Quartz 2.0.

If you are building a separate program from the program that is actually executing the jobs, then you just create a scheduler with the same details but don't call scheduler.Start()

If you are looking to add new jobs to your database you can do something like :

(where SimpleJob is the C# class name of your job)

```
string jobName = ...
string triggerName = ...
string cronExpression = ...  
Quartz.IScheduler scheduler = ... 


Quartz.IJobDetail jobDetail = Quartz.JobBuilder.Create<SimpleJob>()
                    .WithIdentity(jobName)
                    .StoreDurably()
                    .Build();
                    
Quartz.ITrigger trigger = Quartz.TriggerBuilder.Create()
                    .WithIdentity(triggerName)
                    .WithSchedule(Quartz.CronScheduleBuilder.CronSchedule(cronExpression))
                    .ForJob(jobName)
                    .Build();
            
scheduler.ScheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
```

If you are looking to add a job to the database without attaching a trigger

```
Quartz.IJobDetail jobDetail = Quartz.JobBuilder.Create<SimpleJob>()
                    .WithIdentity(jobName)
                    .StoreDurably()
                    .Build();

scheduler.AddJob(jobDetail, false)
```

If you are looking to schedule execute a one-off existing job, then

```
   Quartz.ITrigger trigger1 = Quartz.TriggerBuilder.Create()
                        .WithIdentity(triggerName)
                        .WithSchedule(Quartz.SimpleScheduleBuilder.Create())
                        .ForJob(jobName)
                        .Build();

   scheduler.ScheduleJob(trigger1);
```

Comment: Hi @sgmoore,
Code snippet that you have wrote is the way to obtain information about group and its jobs. This is general way for Quartz  independently from the way of consuming job configurations.
I need the way to load jobs and triggers from Databse instead of XML file or code, that is my question.

Comment: Maybe I have totally misunderstood your question. If you are looking to **add** jobs to your database you normally do that in code by creating Quartz.IJobDetail and Quartz.ITrigger records (see http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/migration_guide.html for one example), and then you call scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger) to add this to your database.

Comment: I have added some examples of how I have added jobs to my database.

Comment: Thank you @sgmoore !
I have just success to add/remove jobs from database and with it to control which jobs are in the game etc. My question was could I manage jobs from database or its purpose is only persistence. Now I know that I can define job details and other configuration and then to run these jobs. It works for me.

Comment: Sir, I couldn't edit this my own but there is a missed closing parenthesis in your code sample. It supposed to be like this .WithSchedule(Quartz.CronScheduleBuilder.CronSchedule(cronExpression))

Comment: @Razor23Donetsk - Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Quartz for java, but since the basic logic is the same I can say that using XML for task schedulers is not a good idea. At every status change of a job, you will need to change the xml file. Using databases (AdoJobStore in your case) might be more efficient.

Comment: Could you give more details, how to define jobs via database and to assign it with scheduler instance ?

Comment: After you set up the db, you should always use the scheduler api to add new jobs. Accessing db directly will cause more problems.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin [implementation](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/blob/e4e71b78bea5a4b7cb41408902207e9880b027ad/src/Quartz/Plugin/Xml/XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin.cs).
basically you need to implement ISchedulerPlugin and add you logic to load jobs.