# How to insert JOB/TRIGGER on database using Quartz.NET?

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I´m using Quart.NET (http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) to scheduler my jobs.
This works perfectly, I can run create job and trigger programatically but I would like to use database to store and create new triggers.

The **quartz.config** changed file is bellow:

> quartz.jobStore.type = Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz
>   quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType = Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.OracleDelegate, Quartz
>   quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_
>   quartz.jobStore.dataSource = myDS
>   quartz.dataSource.myDS.connectionString = ******* my oracle connection string **********
>   quartz.dataSource.myDS.provider = OracleODP-20
>   quartz.jobStore.useProperties = true

I'm using the solution sample of Latest stable version of Quartz.NET is 2.0.1 called **Quartz.Server.2010**, the project play normally and execute *SELECT* in table a each 15 seconds (more or less), but how I *INSERT* data in the quartz tables?

My database has been configured using the script **tables_oracle.sql**

I would not execute *INSERT* manually in the tables, because the schema quartz of database is very dificult.

I have a other project WEB where do I would use to schedule new jobs, this project will insert the data in tables and my project server Quartz.Server.2010 will been execute.

Can I use the method CronExpression to schedule jobs a each 1 minute? like below:

> Quartz.CronExpression cron = new Quartz.CronExpression("0 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *");

But i would like to put it in database, to be consumed by quartz server, and don't run in my web project.

Thanks Friends,

Comment: I'm tring to use Quartz.NET API, but it dont persist in database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You configure your web server to use the same settings as your Quartz Server and you initialise your scheduler the same way, but don't actually start the scheduler (otherwise the jobs will start to run on the webserver).

When you are creating jobs using the API make sure you remember to call .StoreDurably()

See my answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11904667/quartz-job-store-is-related-to-active-data/11917294#11917294) for more details of the syntax.

Comment: Thanks friend. I Missed the put method `.StoreDurably()` in my code. Now is working.